# Какие ns сервера указывать для локальной зоны bind9?

Tags: linux, bind

Создаю локальную зону `lokha.local` в bind9.

По примерам из инета у меня получилась такая зона:

```
;
; Конфиг зоны lokha.local.
;
$TTL    120
@   IN  SOA lokha.local. root.lokha.local. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
              86400 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  lokha.local.
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  AAAA    ::1

; A записи
test    IN  A   66.22.44.25
```

Она работает. Но я не понимаю, зачем нужно указывать это:

```
@   IN  NS  lokha.local.
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
```

И что вообще надо туда указывать? Я `127.0.0.1` по приколу туда вписал, не уверен, что это правильно.
Зона локальная. Я создавал ее, чтобы на моих хостах она была доступна по моему dns-серверу.